# How can i run a specific parametric test-case in py.test in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pytest, liclipse

While *PyDev* supports *py.test* runner, when running [parametric-tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html), it is not possible to run a specific test-case in *PyUnit* view.

Normally, Right-click+Run on a test-case in *PyUnit* view re-launches it - but in this case, nothing happens, and the console logs:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.1, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: D:\project, inifile:
collected 23 items

======================== no tests ran in 0.04 seconds =========================
```

(note that i tried that on Windows only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for running a single parametric failed test case in PyDev (and can't really think of a way to make this work either).

So, you have to run the test which will run it with all the parametric arguments passed (i.e.: use `Ctrl+Shift+Up` / `Ctrl+Shift+Down` to select the test in the editor and then use `Ctrl+F9` to run only that test).